# is it possble to watch live streaming from Justin.tv, Ustream.tv, Freedocast to windows phone 7 media element?

Tags: windows-phone-7, video, streaming, video-streaming

I'm wondering if it's possible to watch live streaming from Justin.tv, Ustream.tv, Freedocast to windows phone 7 media element?

if YES, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible because these sites using Flash. The APIs also require the flash as explained in the [documentation](http://fr.justin.tv/p/api):

> The Justin.tv API is actually made up of two API's: the Rest API and
>   the **Flash Integration API**.

Flash is not supported by Windows Phone